# JAVA drawing rectangle

Tags: java

So I have code like this:

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Rectangle selection = new Rectangle();
        private Point clickPoint;

        private BufferedImage tempimage;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                tempimage = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/droop//omega.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    int minX = Math.min(e.getX(), clickPoint.x);
                    int minY = Math.min(e.getY(), clickPoint.y);
                    int maxX = Math.max(e.getX(), clickPoint.x);
                    int maxY = Math.max(e.getY(), clickPoint.y);

                    selection.x = minX;
                    selection.y = minY;
                    selection.width = maxX - minX;
                    selection.height = maxY - minY;
                    repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    clickPoint = new Point(e.getPoint());
                }

            };

            addMouseListener(ma);
            addMouseMotionListener(ma);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return tempimage == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(tempimage.getWidth(), tempimage.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int x = (getWidth() - tempimage.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - tempimage.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(tempimage, x, y, this);
            if (selection.width > 0 && selection.height > 0) {
                g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 255, 64));
                g2d.fill(selection);
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g2d.draw(selection);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
```

What I am trying to do is: change this code so I can change the picture using a button click. SO I want to have my TestPane created and put on frame but load the image later on with a button click. 
And there is one more problem : sometimes the picture is too big to display on TestPane so I added scrools but then x and y coordinates of the mouse click are not synchronized with drawing the shape. When scrolls are on and I do the mouse click then the rectangle is being drawn above NOT at the exact place.
please help

Comment: Start with [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: *"sometimes the picture is too big to display on TestPane so I added scrools but then x and y coordinates of the mouse click are not synchronized with drawing the shape. When scrolls are on and I do the mouse click then the rectangle is being drawn above NOT at the exact place"* - Use a `JScrollPane`, it will take care of the rest it self

Comment: Hi, so I know how to use JButtons, Action Listeners :P What I have tryed is: I created a button, I put all pictures into an array and with a mouse click I change image and put it on TestPane so I took this code : tempimage = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/droop//omega.jpg")); from the class and change it so with each button click i display new piocture on testPane but then drawin the rectangle is not working....

Comment: Then perhaps you should have posted that code instead/as well

Comment: and I am using the JScrollPane but it is not taking care of the rest... x and y coords are not the same....

Comment: Then you're not using it right, consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Well I have been trying to do it couple of times and I dont have all the code examples I was trying to use. I am sorry. I have posted the only part of the code that is working OK. But give me some time I will try to do it one more time and then I'll post the BAD code

Comment: So I took your code, changed the image, stuck into a scroll pane, resized the window to make the scrollbars appear and the selection highlighting works just fine for me. Gotta love code you find on the internet, oh, wait, that's mine ... pretty awesome isn't ;)

Comment: Well I have noticed this problem when I have moved this:  tempimage = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/droop//omega.jpg")); out of this class. But please wait I will try to write it again and post